# How to pass an AS3 String from an AIR app to an HTML page opened inside an HTML component?

Tags: html, actionscript-3, air, kiosk, virtual-keyboard

I have build a complete AIR kiosk working full screen and included my own designed&developed virtual keyboard for text input. It finds the current textInput that has focus and adds letters or removes them from custom events fired by my keyboard component.

Now my client wants to load some html pages. I use the HTML component that works great, except that when the user enables focus on an html text input (like in www.google.com), my keyboard obviously doesn't work with it.

I guess I need some javascript here in addition to my completely AS3 and MXML code.

Any ideas how to pass a string from the AIR app to the focused html text input?

thanx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the answer is within Html.htmlLoader.window.document.activeElement

thank you so much mich!

http://www.indieas.org/2009/11/onscreen-keyboard-with-air/